# Pylab clip bargraph ends

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to clip the ends of the the bars in a bar graph like [this](http://www.andypope.info/charts/brokencolumn.htm).

Can I use the clip_box or clip_path options of a matplotlib.pyplot.bar?

If so can someone please explain how they work? Where is the origin (0, 0) positioned with respect to each bar?

I have found [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/image_clip_path.html) so far but It still leaves me confused.

**Updated Explanation**
pylab supports breaking an arbitrary graph in 2 about the y axis. In addition to this split I want to append a cut-like design to each of the plot figures which were split. for example imagine a bar-graph made of paper, if I split the bars at a certain point along the y axis by tearing the paper, there will be a rough edge at the split. I am looking to mimic this detail with perhaps some sort of graphic masking tool and I am seeking advice as to whether it is possible to realize this from within pylab.

Comment: Try [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_axis.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I am aware of that example. I would post a better pic if I could. Let me try to explain a little better, see OP.